# Node.Js on windows - How to clear console

Tags: windows, node.js, console, windows-vista

Being totally new into node.js environment and philosophy i would like answers to few questions. I had downloaded the node.js for windows installer and also node package manager.Windows Cmd prompt is being currently used for running nodejs apps.

1. cls clears the command window or errors in command prompt. Is there a equivalent for node.js ? console.clear does not exist ;( or does it in some other form?
2. I created a server through this code below

   ```
   var http = require("http");
   http.createServer(function (request, response) {
       response.writeHead(200, {
           "Content-Type": "text/html"
       });
       response.write("Hello World");
       console.log("welcome world")response.end();
   }).listen(9000, "127.0.0.1");
   ```

i changed the code to below and refreshed the browser to find that content type does not change, how do i get to see the changes?

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  console.log("welcome world")
  response.end();
}).listen(9000,"127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Restart the server to see changes

Comment: @Raynos how do i do that. Close the command prompt and open it again? man i would start to hate NodeJs then. There is no way to clear console?

Comment: clear what console? The windows cmd shell or powershell or unix shell? Have you tried `cls` or `clear` ?

Comment: For those who want to clear the consol history/suggestion:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35016953/1486850

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
console.log('\033[2J');
```

This works on linux. Not sure about windows.

You can "trick" the user using something like this:

```
var lines = process.stdout.getWindowSize()[1];
for(var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    console.log('\r\n');
}
```

Comment: Only the second "trick" worked for me, [rest all the answers were useless](http://i.imgur.com/oNIRSMO.png).  Using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) on windows8

Comment: in case somebody stubles this. On windows: `process.stdout.write('\033c');`, as `'\033[2J'` only clears current application stream, and `'\033c'` resets std

Comment: This is an [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), in case y'all were curious (I was).  The `\033` is the octal number of ESC in ASCII.  With the bracket it forms the CSI (Control Sequence Introducer).  `0J`, `1J`, and `2J` clear top, bottom, and entire screen, respectively.

Comment: @TedNyberg You're correct that it won't work in strict mode (octal literal) but you can get around this by using "\x1BC" or "\x1B[EJ" depending on what you need.

Comment: @TedNyberg in addition to hex literals (\x...) unicode literals (\u...) such as in Iaktak's answer work as well.

Comment: on windows 10 sending special characters failed to prevent scrolling back, but this worked: `require('child_process').execSync('cls', {stdio: 'inherit'});`

Comment: Octal escape sequences not allowed -> change to hex "\x1bc"

Answer (score 84):

```
process.stdout.write('\033c');
```

This also works on windows. Win7 at least.

Comment: This was the only escape sequence listed here that worked for me on Server 2008 r2 and it also works nicely on my Windows 7 system.

Comment: Works on 10 as well.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it is cross-platform and doesn't leave white space after clearing.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu.

Comment: Works on mac (10.15.x)

Comment: Octal escape sequences not allowed -> change to hex "\x1bc"

Answer (score 57):

This is for **Linux** mainly; but is also reported to work in Windows.

There is <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd> in Gnome Terminal that clears the terminal. It can be used with Python, Node JS or any other REPL running in terminal. It has the same effect as `clear` command.

Comment: Ctrl+L clears the screen when using node in windows 8 command prompt

Comment: This should be preferred answer because node REPL uses gnom-terminal so ctrl+l works on windows as well.

Comment: Great suggestion! This clears the screen, leaving only the > and cursor.

Comment: Windows 10. Gives the appearance that it cleared by scrolling previous content out of view. If you scroll up, the old content still re-appears.

Comment: There is reset command in Linux for this. But should be given in Terminal.

Comment: if 'Ctrl+L' press then your terminal like this '^L' then just ENTER press and console clear DONE. FOR Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 56):

This clears the console on Windows and puts the cursor at 0,0:

```
var util = require('util');
util.print("\u001b[2J\u001b[0;0H");
```

[or](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21285616/669677)

```
process.stdout.write("\u001b[2J\u001b[0;0H");
```

Comment: Are you sure this works on windows? I know that windows hates almost all ansi escape codes.

Comment: Yes, I am using it. The codes are probably interpreted by nodejs.

Comment: *and* this works in strict mode which complains about octal literal when using the \033 solutions

Comment: I prefer this to the accepted answer; resetting back to 0,0 gives you closer to a proper 'cls' in Windows 10 Powershell.

Comment: This does works on bash as well. Thanks

Comment: Property 'print' does not exist on type 'typeof import("util")'.

Comment: `process.stdout.write("\u001b[2J\u001b[0;0H");` is the only answer that worked for me in strict mode.

Answer (score 51):

i am using a windows CMD and this worked for me

```
console.clear();
```

Comment: This also works for Node.js v14.0.0 on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) in the terminal

Comment: This caused me unexpected output: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/435643/tabla-de-multiplicar-da-resultados-inesperados?noredirect=1#comment777599_435643

Comment: This works on Linux as well

Answer (score 44):

And to clear the console while in strict mode on Windows:

```
'use strict';
process.stdout.write('\x1Bc');
```

Comment: This one worked and didn't trigger [a JSDoc error](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1263)

Comment: Worked on all platforms too (CMD, Cmder, GitBash, Ubuntu).

Comment: I tried it with `cosole.log('\x1Bc')` and it works , simple than other solutions, strict mode wasn't necessary.

Comment: works on MAC OS Mojave, and clears full log.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 21):

Starting from Node.JS **v8.3.0** you can use method [clear](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_clear):

```
console.clear()
```

Comment: I came here because this is what I've already done and it actually works inconsitently(

Comment: Best answer ever. 
Without any dances with a tambourine  xD

Answer (score 16):

Just use `CTRL + L` on windows to clear the console.

Answer (score 8):

Haven't tested this on Windows but works on unix. The trick is in the `child_process` module. Check the documentation. You can save this code as a file and load it to the REPL every time you need it.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function clear(){
    exec('clear', function(error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log(stdout);
    });    
}
```

Comment: my guess is that you'd need "cls" for Windows since "clear" is a *nix command.

Comment: we can put `clear || cls` not sure if windows support `||` though

Answer (score 6):

To solve problems with strict mode:

```
'use strict';
process.stdout.write('\x1B[2J');
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use the official way:

```js
console.log('Blah blah blah'); // Prints "Blah blah blah"

console.clear(); // Clears, or in other words, resets the terminal.

console.log('You will only see this message. No more Blah blah blah...');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **`VSCode`** you can use **`CTRL + K`**. I know this is not a generic solution but may help some people.

Comment: Also works on PHPStorm. `Ctrl+K` looks to be the only solution, when node.js doesn't restore the console on the next run.

Answer (score 1):

Based on sanatgersappa's answer and some other info I found, here's what I've come up with:

```
function clear() {
    var stdout = "";

    if (process.platform.indexOf("win") != 0) {
        stdout += "\033[2J";
    } else {
        var lines = process.stdout.getWindowSize()[1];

        for (var i=0; i<lines; i++) {
            stdout += "\r\n";
        }
    }

    // Reset cursur
    stdout += "\033[0f";

    process.stdout.write(stdout);
}
```

**To make things easier**, I've released this as an npm package called [cli-clear](https://npmjs.org/cli-clear).

Comment: Some fun: With `"\u001b[32;1m"` you can set even the color of text (in Windows command line) (- undo code: `"\u001b\x1b[0m"`) more info: http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the `readline` module:**

`readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, 0)` moves the cursor to (0, 0).

`readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0)` clears the current line.

`readline.clearScreenDown(process.stdout)` clears everything below the cursor.

```
const READLINE = require('readline');

function clear() {
    READLINE.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, 0);
    READLINE.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
    READLINE.clearScreenDown(process.stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On package.json try this:

```
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "events": {
      "start": "clear"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the above to work.  I'm using nodemon for development and found this the easiest way to clear the console:

```
  console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
```

It just scrolls the console several lines so you get a clear screen for subsequent console.log commands.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: `console.log('\n'.repeat(999))`

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine on my node.js server console Windows 7.

`process.stdout.write("\u001b[0J\u001b[1J\u001b[2J\u001b[0;0H\u001b[0;0W");`

Answer (score 0):

On mac, I simply use **Cmd + K** to clear the console, very handy and better than adding codes inside your project to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Belated, but ctrl+l works in windows if you're using powershell :) Powershell + chocolatey + node + npm = winning.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd> This is the best, simplest and most effective option.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I did it to loop for ever and show in the console a number ever in a single line:

```
class Status {

  private numberOfMessagesInTheQueue: number;
  private queueName: string;

  public constructor() {
    this.queueName = "Test Queue";
    this.numberOfMessagesInTheQueue = 0;
    this.main();
  }

  private async main(): Promise<any> {    
    while(true) {
      this.numberOfMessagesInTheQueue++;
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(_ => resolve(this.showResults(this.numberOfMessagesInTheQueue)), 1500);
      });
    }
  }

  private showResults(numberOfMessagesInTheQuee: number): void {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`Number of messages in the queue ${this.queueName}: ${numberOfMessagesInTheQuee}.`)
  }
}

export default new Status();
```

When you run this code you will see the same message "Number of messages in the queue Test Queue: 1." and the number changing (1..2..3, etc).