# Clear command history of NodeJS REPL Console

Tags: node.js, command-line, console, command

I am using NodeJS version 4.2.1

I want to know the command for clearing the NodeJS REPL console history completely so it doesn't show previously executed commands when Up or Down arrow keys are pressed.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 14):

The answer is actually simple :)

On Windows (my version is 10):

1. go to user folder: `cd %userprofile%`
2. empty file named **.node_repl_history** (in my case with vim text-editor) OR you can simple run: `echo. > .node_repl_history` and it will have same effect.

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 20.04 - can be found in $HOME/.node_repl_history

Comment: Also works on Mac Monterey 12.0.1 - file is also located at `~/.node_repl_history`

Answer (score 10):

Per the nodejs documentation which can be found at the following link:

[nodejs repl](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html)

**Environment Variable Options**

> The built-in repl (invoked by running
>   node or node -i) may be controlled via the following environment
>   variables:
>
> NODE_REPL_HISTORY - When a valid path is given, persistent REPL
>   history will be saved to the specified file rather than
>   .node_repl_history in the user's home directory. Setting this value to
>   "" will disable persistent REPL history. NODE_REPL_HISTORY_SIZE -
>   defaults to 1000. Controls how many lines of history will be persisted
>   if history is available. Must be a positive number. NODE_REPL_MODE -
>   may be any of sloppy, strict, or magic. Defaults to magic, which will
>   automatically run "strict mode only" statements in strict mode.

**Persistent History**

> By default, the REPL will persist history between
>   node REPL sessions by saving to a .node_repl_history file in the
>   user's home directory. This can be disabled by setting the environment
>   variable NODE_REPL_HISTORY="".

Answer (score 0):

In your node js server just do like this :

```
    app.listen(5600,() => {
        console.clear();
        console.log('Server app listening on port 5600');
    });
```