# How give a app name instead of "sudo sails lift" i.e. own app Name or commandline?

Tags: sails.js

How give a app NAME instead of "sudo sails lift"? own app Name or commandline? How can I create a own app name instead of this "sails lift" and without the boat (graphic) there, when do you lift the app?

How to create a own commandline for sails app? like app name etc? I get this every time.. but I want change it to a own graphic with out the boat and sails lift? how doing that and where?

```
info: Starting app...

info: 
info:                .-..-.
info: 
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.11.5             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------' 
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info: 
info: Server lifted in `/Users/cyberspace/Documents/Apps/www.project.com/project/myapp`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.
```

Comment: You can always change the code in sails but it will be erased with an `npm install`... you can also launch with `node app.js` and add your custom message after clearing the console http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006988/node-js-on-windows-how-to-clear-console

Comment: me too here! it's only a start script.. but i have a app gitlist OS here : https://github.com/SpaceG/gitlist.io and make me fit for this : a sails.js developer say me that. please, have take a look : http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/programmatic-usage and google about - " Configuring, starting and stopping Sails apps programmatically in node.js"

Comment: i have one : here download : tilda https://github.com/SpaceG/gitlist.io/blob/master/cli.js then create a <code>cli.js </code> file. then in your https://github.com/SpaceG/gitlist.io/blob/master/package.json and these stips <pre>  "bin": {
    "gitlist": "./cli.js"
  },  </pre> see the tree example : https://github.com/SpaceG/gitlist.io don't forget the gitgnore : https://github.com/SpaceG/gitlist.io/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: someone have a idea? now? I'm stuck here since some days.

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete overview on how to run a Sails app via a script on the Sails doc site, under [programmatic usage](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/programmatic-usage), as well as a full reference of the Sails application object in the [application section](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/application).  Between those two there are more than enough examples to let you build your own command-line app, which can be as simple as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// Make sure that no matter where we call the command from,
// we lift the app that lives in the same directory as this script
process.chdir(__dirname);
// Get an instance of Sails
var sails = require('sails');
// Lift the Sails app in the current working directory
sails.lift();
```

If you want to get rid of the initial ship message, you can set `sails.config.log.noShip` to `true`:

```
sails.lift({log:{noShip: true}});
```

You can also take a shortcut by just copying the `app.js` file that comes with every new Sails project and adding `#!/usr/bin/env node` to the top of it.  Either way, make sure your CLI script is executable:

```
chmod +x ./myapp
```

Comment: OK : NEW CHANGES : i have left the <code>app.js</code>  blank (however why?) ... and but that code example of you: in that cli.js file. : it works... Now with the Commandline <code>$ sudo gitlist lift </code> but i want to understanding why.... ?... thats ipmortant when do you learning to Code Apps. But Thanks alot Mr. sgress454