# NodeJS console log buffer - how to clear

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I'm running nodejs (using nodemon) and outputting a ton of stuff to the console for debug.

But when the app is stopped and restarted, the entire historical console log output is re-displayed. How do I clear that?

Doing something like this in the app:

`console.log('\x1Bc');`

...will clear the current console screen but **not** the buffered log which re-appears when the app is restarted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.Js on windows - How to clear console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006988/node-js-on-windows-how-to-clear-console)

Comment: Not a dupe. That issue is the current console screen. My issue is the buffered output (log) that will re-appear when the app is restarted.

Comment: you must have some code that outputs the log again then.

Comment: `\x1b[2J` work?

Comment: Though this is an old question, if I understand the question correctly, I believe the correct term for the thing OP is talking about is "Scrollback buffer/ScreenBuffer".