# How to log console on same line or clear console in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a file like so:

```
for (let i = 100; i--){
  console.log(i);
}
```

How can I make this console each number in the same place:

```
console.log(99 --> changes to 98, 97, 96)
```

Instead of :

```
console.log(99);
console.log(98);
console.log(97);
...
```

Comment: If this is browser-side (vs. server-side Node.js), you can't.  `console.log` will always append a newline.

Comment: This is server side , node is server side

Comment: If, however, this is server-side, you can use `process.stdout.write` instead of `console`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628935/1810460)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006988/node-js-on-windows-how-to-clear-console

Comment: @Hamms Since I said this was in node which is server-side code, put your code as an answer because it worked.

Comment: @TaylorAustin next time i'd tag this Q as node.js... and as such this should be closed as a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use`console.log('\033[2J');` after each `console.log()` call.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. At least in the chrome console each console.log is still it's own line (\033[2J resolves to one empty line).

Comment: In chrome you need to change the [preserve log upon navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear) setting.

Comment: This won't work in strict mode

Comment: Using node 18 I got "SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode."